# Alamofire Getting Response -999 = cancelled using URLRequestConvertible

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a problem about Alamofire 3.0, I'm trying to get the data from the server with authentication. When i run it to my device iphone 6 ios 9.2.1 have no response, but in iphone 6 ios 9.2 simulator have response.

I follow how it is created in alamofire documentation in : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#crud--authorization

Appreciate your answers.

class APIController {

```
 ...


enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "link_with_user:password"
    static var OAuthToken: String?

    case myListing([String: AnyObject])

    var method: Alamofire.Method {
        switch self {

        case .myListing:return .GET
        }
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {

        case .myListing:
            return "Listing.php"

        }
    }

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!
        let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

        if let token = Router.OAuthToken {
            mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
            mutableURLRequest.setValue("Basic \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }

        switch self {
        case .myListing(let parameters):
            return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
        default:
            return mutableURLRequest
        }
    }
}


func getListing(){
   //This is how i call the enum
    Alamofire.request(Router.myListing(parameters!))
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Just to clarify. On iPhone you don't see response because `print("JSON: \(JSON)")` line is not triggered, or the whole `.responseJSON{...}` block is not called? Have you tried to put `debugPrint(response)` just before `if let JSON =....` line?

Comment: Hi @euvs , the line print("JSON: \(JSON)") is not triggered, i put ur suggestion debugPrint(response) but this what i got: 

[Response]: nil
[Data]: 0 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

Comment: it seems that network request was issued but got cancelled for some reason. Try googling for that error and see what's the problem might be and how to solve it.

Comment: Hi euvs, the problem is, if i use simulator and my connection has a proxy from the server, i can retrieve the data. but when using device without proxy and other internet connection it will return nil. Do you have any idea, what approach i can use? thank you!